# Visual C# Express solution file

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I can't open a Visual Studio 2008 Windows application solution file into Visual C# Express. How can I fix this?

Comment: What errors are you encountering?

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio express doesnt understand a visual studio 2008 sln/csproj file. You will need to make another sln/csproj file in visual C# express and re-add all your cs files into it.

The error you should get is a message saying sln not supported. There is no simple way to fix without damaging your sln/csproj file.